# Android Out of Memory at setContentView

Tags: android

I've made a full screen click-through app that has 6 screens. The app goes from screen upon a click. Each screen has it's own activity (Step1, Step2, Step3 etc until Step 6). Nothing complicated, layouts are very simple, only a background image and a button to press. I get to about screen 3 when problems start, suddenly the next screen will not show up but the app crashes in out of memory error. I've tried moving to screens 4, 5, 6, no luck, but if I move back to say screen 2 from screen 3, then it works! Something leaks, but I don't know what. The background images are small.

I'm changing between Activities with this code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Step3.this, Step6.class); 
Step3.this.startActivity(myIntent); 
System.gc();
```

This is the log:

```
03-05 12:38:44.090: D/dalvikvm(22184): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
03-05 12:38:44.115: D/dalvikvm(22184): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3622K, 8% free 55598K/59911K, paused 1ms+3ms, total 22ms
03-05 12:39:33.965: D/dalvikvm(22184): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
03-05 12:39:34.040: D/dalvikvm(22184): GC_EXPLICIT freed 31K, 8% free 55633K/59911K, paused 11ms+5ms, total 74ms
03-05 12:39:34.040: I/Choreographer(22184): Skipped 2910 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 12:39:43.850: D/dalvikvm(22184): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 34K, 8% free 55613K/59911K, paused 23ms, total 24ms
03-05 12:39:43.860: I/dalvikvm-heap(22184): Grow heap (frag case) to 58.364MB for 3686416-byte allocation
03-05 12:39:43.900: D/dalvikvm(22184): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 7% free 59213K/63559K, paused 14ms+5ms, total 39ms
03-05 12:39:43.935: D/dalvikvm(22184): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 7% free 59213K/63559K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
03-05 12:39:43.935: I/dalvikvm-heap(22184): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 14745616-byte allocation
03-05 12:39:43.955: D/dalvikvm(22184): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed <1K, 7% free 59213K/63559K, paused 18ms, total 19ms
03-05 12:39:43.955: E/dalvikvm-heap(22184): Out of memory on a 14745616-byte allocation.
03-05 12:39:43.955: I/dalvikvm(22184): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
03-05 12:39:43.955: I/dalvikvm(22184):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x413f0508 self=0x413e0468
03-05 12:39:43.955: I/dalvikvm(22184):   | sysTid=22184 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074609968
03-05 12:39:43.955: I/dalvikvm(22184):   | schedstat=( 1501533493 98715963 900 ) utm=116 stm=33 core=3
03-05 12:39:43.955: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
03-05 12:39:43.955: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
03-05 12:39:43.955: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:476)
03-05 12:39:43.955: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
03-05 12:39:43.955: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1963)
03-05 12:39:43.955: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
03-05 12:39:43.955: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:308)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at com.frogr4g.networktrial.Step6.onCreate(Step6.java:11)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
03-05 12:39:43.960: I/dalvikvm(22184):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 12:39:43.960: A/libc(22184): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 22184 (4g.networktrial)
03-05 12:39:57.150: D/dalvikvm(22766): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 64K, 6% free 12115K/12867K, paused 34ms, total 35ms
03-05 12:39:57.155: I/dalvikvm-heap(22766): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.883MB for 3686416-byte allocation
03-05 12:39:57.170: D/dalvikvm(22766): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 15714K/16519K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 14ms
```

EDIT: I created a similar app of six screens, just with textview and a button and a navigation chain (1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6 --> 1) without any images, and it works like butter. (as expected). So it's definitely something to do with the images taking up lots of memory.

Comment: Use Memory Analyzer tool to find out where is memory leak. It's hard to tell where is the problem without seeing your code.

Comment: If you don't have to go back, you can always finish current activity before starting a new one.

Comment: tundundun, will have to look into that, thanks for the tip. Looks a bit intimidating though.

Comment: Niko, tried that, no effect. Still crashes.

Comment: I have the same problem. My app crashes in android versions over 3.0 right after setContentView.  I have some imageViews and ImageButtons in my layout xmls and of course background image.

Did you find any workaround on this?

Comment: I got this issue too today in one of my app. No bitmaps either, not sure what to do. Please suggest something if you got any solutions, and its happening only in the full hd resolution devices(xxhdpi)

Answer (score 2):

A few things to look at.

- Have you provided the background image(s) for several densities? Scaling is sometimes consuming a lot of memory.
- Do you use `startActivity` or `startActivityForResult()`? In the latter case, your older Activity objects cannot be destroyed.
- Do you collect information in the `Application` class?

Comment: NO I have not provided several densities. I'm using startActivity. I'm not using Application class for storing any variables, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @Pompair What size are your images, and what format, and do you implicitly request they get scaled? Even a relatively small JPG will consume quite some memory when Android has to scale it. Providing images for ddifferent densities may help to avoid this.

Comment: Class Stacker, images are 720x1280 32-bit pngs, about 20kB each. I don't know what implicit request for scaling means...I'm using default imageview settings stretched to fit the size of the activity. Which folder should I put the images if I want to run on Samsung S3? Is drawable-hdpi folder where pngs should go...?

Comment: @Pompair No matter what size, if Android decompresses your PNG, at 720 x 1280 x 4 Byte, the resulting bitmap may be as big as 3.5MB. Yes, if you ask Android to stretch it, then it's going to be scaled. Scaling probably involves decompressing the PNG and creating a second (destination) bitmap. If you try and just have your images cropped instead of scaled, does your app perform better?

Answer (score 1):

`recycle()` your Bitmaps as soon as you leave an activity to go to the other and reorder code:

```
bitmap.recycle();
System.gc();
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Step3.this, Step6.class); 
Step3.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using bitmaps, but imageviews.