# How to triage a large memory allocation in `setContentView()`?

Tags: android, android-layout, out-of-memory

We are developing an Android app that makes makes much use of images (small and large). Our home screen has a "collage" of images.  We have debugged a series of "memory leaks" through [the usual mechanisms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223054/android-out-of-memory-at-setcontentview)... but have just noticed that our call to `setContentView` in our main `Activity` causes a very large memory allocation:

> 08-14 15:27:30.688: D/BEFORE setContentView PJK 6 CollageActivity(21845): debug.memory: allocated: 49.05MB of 192.00MB (19.22MB free)
>   08-14 15:27:31.049: D/AFTER setContentView PJK 7 CollageActivity(21845): debug.memory: allocated: 64.68MB of 192.00MB (15.22MB free)

(This was taken from a Nexus 4 device).

The only thing in the above-liked SO question we haven't tried is generating different-scaled background images.  This would only account for 3,932,160 (= 1280 x 768 x 4) bytes of allocation.

DDMS (and MAT) shows that there is a large allocation to bitmaps:

[image: MAT]

Is there some way to figure out which part of our layout is causing such a large allocation (16,384,064 bytes!) ? (Though I just rescaled the image to that size, and it didn't help.)

---

**EDIT**

Digging a little deeper, I removed the `android:background` drawable from the `LinearLayout`:

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/collage_activity_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_collage"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

And the memory allocation when away!  Any ideas as to why the 800 x 1280 background ( which should generate a 800 x 1280 x 4= 4,096,000 byte image) is actually generating a 16MB image? Could it be because of the difference between 800 (image size) and 768 (screen size) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a two things that we had to do to fix this:

1. The background images we were using were JPGs.  Changing the images to PNGs (for both orientations) dropped the usage from 16MB to about 8MB.
2. The images also had to be scaled down by 25% in each direction.  That gave us a much more manageable allocation per orientation change (about 2MB).

Answer (score -1):

yes we can see the heap growth in debug mode and update heap thread to see heap update at runtime .
just go to the DDMS and debug your app process and click update heap button and see in heap tab on right side